# Как сделать html комментарии невидимыми?

Tags: html, html5, комментарии

Как сделать html комментарии невидимыми? то есть  при отладке или при просмотре содержимого странички в html формате не отображались комментарии?

Comment: никак, только совсем удалять их

Comment: Наверняка современные "сборщики" перед отправкой клиенту сделают это за вас. Хотя тут я не уверен в том, что файлы с разметкой тоже чистятся.

Comment: Ну или написать скрипт, который будет удалять комментарии при деплое и обратно возвращать для редактирования. В линуксе например можно почистить регулярками, затем сделать patch файл с помощью diff. О когда потребуется изменять файл - пропатчить его комментами

Answer (score 0):

никак. если вам нужно сохранить комментарий, но не писать его в код страницы, можно воспользоваться блокнотом, в котором указать комментарий к строке